# Syntax error or access violation for simple search

Tags: cakephp

i try to make a search but i end up with error:

in my controller i wrote:

```
public function search() {
  $this->set('results',$this->History->search($this->data['History']['searchtext']));
}
```

in my views i wrote:

//#View/Histories/searchall.ctp

```
<?php

    echo $this->Form->create("History",array('action' => 'search'));
    echo $this->Form->input("searchtext", array('label' => 'Search for'));
    echo $this->Form->end("Search");
?>
```

and it returns

```
"Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'search' at line 1" in my search.ctp
```

in My History Model i wrote:

```
<?php
  class History extends AppModel{
  var $name='History';
  var $actsAs=array('Searchable');
}
```

?>

Comment: Do you have a `search` method in your `History` model?

Comment: Also, you showed the view for `searchall`, but the action in your *Controller* is called `search`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the cakeDC search-Plugin. Its very easy to handle and very flexible.
You only have to install it.
the configuration is very easy. 
https://github.com/CakeDC/search